# Unknown parameter format in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have this route

```
Route::name('recruitment.edit.profile')->get('/edit-profile/{id}', 'EmployeeController@showEditProfileForm');
```

having a parameter `id` and

this code in my blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('recruitment.edit.profile', $users->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">
  <i class="fa fa-edit m-right-xs"></i> Edit Profile
</a>
```

But when I clicked the given link I got this url `http://mpci-vo.dev/recruitment/edit-profile?9` and a message `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

My question why is there a `?` before `9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `route('recruitment.edit.profile', $users->id)`

to

`route('recruitment.edit.profile', ['id' => $users->id])`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route